# The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [clientInboundChannel-32] but has failed to stop it

Tags: spring-boot, websocket

Sometimes my Spring Boot integration tests fail due to OutOfMemoryError. I never figured out why this happens, but I found out that this happens right after my tests related to websockets are completed. I solved this by increasing the `maxHeapSize` in `build.gradle`, but this solution is way from optimal.

When I run the tests locally, I am getting this error:

```
 java.base@17.0.6/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
 java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
2023-07-24 13:26:32.113  WARN 42956 --- [           main] o.a.c.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase       : The web application [ROOT] appears to have started a thread named [clientInboundChannel-32] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak. Stack trace of thread:
 java.base@17.0.6/jdk.internal.misc.Unsafe.park(Native Method)
 java.base@17.0.6/java.util.concurrent.locks.LockSupport.parkNanos(LockSupport.java:252)
 java.base@17.0.6/java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer$ConditionObject.awaitNanos(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1672)
 java.base@17.0.6/java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingQueue.poll(LinkedBlockingQueue.java:460)
 java.base@17.0.6/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.getTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1061)
 java.base@17.0.6/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1122)
 java.base@17.0.6/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
 java.base@17.0.6/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Not sure if it's related. But I guess it might be.

In the tests I have an util for websocket testing and I am closing the connection after the tests.

You can see the code [here](https://github.com/tolgee/tolgee-platform/blob/e47b4e5fdebb94dfbdce8c16a52656ab85cef9f3/backend/app/src/test/kotlin/io/tolgee/websocket/WebsocketTestHelper.kt#L4).

And the usage [here](https://github.com/tolgee/tolgee-platform/blob/e47b4e5fdebb94dfbdce8c16a52656ab85cef9f3/backend/app/src/test/kotlin/io/tolgee/websocket/AbstractWebsocketTest.kt#L4).

Any ideas?

Comment: Glancing at your code I did see a lot of `@SpringBootTest` with various different `@MockBean` annotations or different properties. Each of those combinations will start a full new Spring Boot application. Make sure that that really is what you want or that you should prefer `@WebMvcTest` or just a basic unit test without Spring Boot. Spring Test framework will cache a number of applications (32 by default IIRC) and each will eat-up memory.

Comment: Well, yeah. Theoretically you're right. But from my experience, it's almost impossible to test the codebase reliably using separate unit tests or tests with smaller contexts like using @WebMvcTest.